Generate speech file corresponding to a webpage content
I am looking for a gratis web service that can generate a speech file corresponding to a webpage content. Google NotebookLM can only generate a dialog:



One can use this Chrome extension to do text-to-speech for a webpage: Read Aloud: A Text to Speech Voice Reader. Gratis, has over 6 million users.
I tried it on:

https://www.wired.com/story/science-corporation-neuralink-eye-implant-restored-vision-blind-people/
https://darioamodei.com/machines-of-loving-grace

Worked well.
Then audio capture to save as a file.
